# Replacing %20 with underscores in a URL using Python and web2py

Tags: python, url, web2py

Inside this code I have an 'args' value which is 'title.title', this value displays in my URL.

How do I make the url read like this: "index.html/something_something" instead how how it displays now, which is: "index.html/something%20something".

```
 def livesearch():
    '''Auto completes the search query'''
    partialstr = request.vars.partialstr
    query = db.listing.title.like('%'+partialstr+'%')
    titles = db(query).select(db.listing.ALL)
    items = []

    for title in titles:
        items.append(DIV(A(title.title, _id="resultLiveSearch", _href=URL('search', args='%s' % title.title))))

    return TAG[''](*items)
```

I tried making it:

```
_href=URL('search', args='%s' % title.title.replace("%20","_")
```

Which I thought would work, but it didn't, what am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%20` is a replacement for a single white space, so you should replace spaces with underscores before passing them to `URL`:

```
title.title.replace(' ', '_')
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on FB's answer: URL() invokes url lib.quote on the args portion of your URL, which does the %-escaping of spaces and other special characters. [\w./-] are not quoted. (If you're following along in the source, this happens in gluon.html.URL.)

When the resulting URL is used (that is, it's the URL that generates a new request), the args are unquoted. So (in your case) a title like "foo bar" would be encoded as foo%20bar in the URL, but then decoded as "foo bar" in request.args when the URL is invoked.

When you do your own encoding (in this case changing "foo bar" to "foo_bar"), you'll get "foo_bar" in request.args and will need to do your own decoding.